# Embaded Youtube video not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, youtube

I embed video from youtube at mobile app with Cordova 
I get this video by ajax as jason data.
when I test it by visual studio or Phongap server is working.
but when test it with Mobile Phone it's not working.
It give me this error : net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.
this is my config.xml

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.phonegap.Elshanabera" 
  version="1.0.0">
 <name></name>
 <description></description>
<author href="http://technoteampro.com" 
  email="info@technoteampro.com">TechnoTeam</author>
 <content src="index.html" />
 <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" 
  />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" 
  spec="~1.2.0" />
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*" launch-external="yes"/>
 <allow-intent href="https://*/*" launch-external="yes"/>

 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
  <platform name="android">
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi" 
/>
 <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" 
  density="xxxhdpi" 
  />
  <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" 
 density="land-ldpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" 
 density="land-mdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" 
 density="land-hdpi" />
 <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" 
   density="land-xhdpi" />
 <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" 
 density="land-xxhdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" 
density="land-xxxhdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" 
density="port-ldpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" 
density="port-mdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" 
density="port-hdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" 
density="port-xhdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" 
 density="port-xxhdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" 
density="port-xxxhdpi" />
 </platform>
 <platform name="ios">
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" 
height="57" 
  />
   <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" platform="ios" width="114" 
  height="114" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" 
  height="40" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" 
  height="80" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" platform="ios" width="50" 
   height="50" />
   <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" platform="ios" width="100" 
  height="100" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" 
 height="60" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" 
    height="120" />
   <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" 
   height="180" />
   <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" platform="ios" width="72" 
   height="72" />
   <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" platform="ios" width="144" 
  height="144" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" 
  height="76" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" 
  height="152" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" 
   height="29" />
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" 
  height="58" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" platform="ios" width="87" 
height="87" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" 
width="640" height="1136" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" platform="ios" width="750" 
  height="1334" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" platform="ios" 
 width="1242" height="2208" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" platform="ios" 
   width="2208" height="1242" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" 
 platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" platform="ios" 
width="1024" height="768" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" 
width="1536" height="2048" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" platform="ios" 
width="768" height="1024" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" 
width="640" height="960" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" platform="ios" 
width="320" height="480" />
</platform>
<platform name="wp8">
<icon src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" platform="wp8" width="99" 
 height="99" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" platform="wp8" width="159" 
height="159" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" platform="wp8" 
 width="768" height="1280" />
 </platform>
<platform name="windows">
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" 
platform="windows" width="150" height="150" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" 
platform="windows" width="30" height="30" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" 
 width="50" height="50" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" 
platform="windows" width="620" height="300" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" 
width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" 
platform="windows" width="44" height="44" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" 
 platform="windows" width="106" height="106" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" 
platform="windows" width="70" height="70" />
   <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" 
 platform="windows" width="71" height="71" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" 
   platform="windows" width="170" height="170" />
     <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" 
     platform="windows" width="360" height="360" />
   <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" 
 platform="windows" width="310" height="310" />
 <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" 
 platform="windows" width="310" height="150" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" 
 platform="windows" width="744" height="360" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" 
 platform="windows" width="1152" height="1920" />
 </platform>
   <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
  <allow-intent href="market:*" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
   <access origin="*" />

  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
   <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
   <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
   <access origin="*" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
   </platform>
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" version="1.1.0" />
  </widget>
```